# mitmproxy, how to get the response time/duration of a call?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am able to get the response code, body, url and querystring form a request and response but I am not able to fetch time taken by a call.

We have

- flow.response.code
- flow.response.content
- flow.response.url

does mitm has anything to get duration for the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mitmproxy datastructures are documented at http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/dev/models.html.

For example:

```
def request(context, flow):
    print(flow.request.timestamp_start)
```

Comment: I suppose you can update this answer after your answer here https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3304